# trouble with interrupting a Batch file started with VBA

Tags: vba, batch-file

I have an Excel file with a lot of PC's names in a server, I want to execute the "systeminfo" command and get the OS out of it. Then the OS shall be put into an Excel cell automatically. To do so, I used the following codes, respectively in the VBA file and the batch file.
however, whenever the server can't reach a pc, the cmd window is stuck until I manually close it. Since the list is actually 148 names long, knowing of a way to automatically close those Windows after, say, 8 seconds would be really helpful.

I tried to look up for a way to multi-thread VBA, just to find out that It is a single-threaded Language. I then tried to start another batch file with the one I'm actually using as to forcefuly kill it afetr a set of time, but it seems that the second batch starts only after the first is terminated, making it useless.

`VBA`

```
Sub Test()

' 
' Test Macro
' I'm not an expert in VBA, I just picked it up for this task, so a lot of code will result redundant. Bear with me
'
'
    Dim i As Integer
    'a is basically i-1. 
    a = 1

    ' I needed 148 cells for the project
    Dim models(1 To 147) As String
    For i = 2 To 148
        models(a) = Cells(i, 3).Value
        a = a + 1
    Next i

    a = 1
    For i = 2 To 148

       'not totally sure what the next five lines actually do, but "metodo" is the name of the batch file.

        Dim strShellCommand As String
        strShellCommand = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\metodo.bat " + models(a)

        Set oSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set oEx = oSh.Exec(strShellCommand)

        strBuf = oEx.StdOut.readAll

        'I took out of the string everything that wasn't purely the OS name

        Dim FinalString As String
        FinalString = Right(strBuf, 26)
        FinalString = Left(FinalString, 25)

        'this is the line that prints the OS names into Excel cells

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10) = FinalString

        a = a + 1
    Next i     

End Sub
```

then there is the Batch file

```
 set nome=%1
 shift
 systeminfo /s %nome% |findstr /c:"Microsoft Windows "
```

Comment: I do not see any benefit in doing it this way, what's stopping you from doing this directly from VBA, _using `GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")`_?

Comment: Instead of running a batch file I'd try to execute `systeminfo` directly or follow Compo's advice...

Answer (score 0):

u can do a control loop after the Set oEx = oSh.Exec(strShellCommand)

like :

```
 Set oEx = oSh.Exec(strShellCommand)
 LoopCount = 0
 Do 'Control loop
    wscript.Sleep 1000
   If TimeOut > 0 Then LoopCount = LoopCount + 1
  Loop Until (oEx.Status <> 0) Or (LoopCount > TimeOut * 8)
  If oEx.Status = 0 Then 'Timeout occured
    oEx.Terminate 
    ReturnValue = "[Process terminated after timeout!]" & VbCrLf 
  Else
    ReturnValue = "[Process completed]" & VbCrLf  
  End If
```

each loop takes 1 second  (wscript.Sleep 1000) and the (LoopCount > TimeOut * 8) sets the total time to 8 seconds

good luck